# Spring Mongo Log4j customize

Tags: spring, mongodb, log4j, spring-data

How can I customize the Spring log4j output into the Mongo datastore?

I was able to follow the Spring's example on how to use MongoLog4j. The logs are being persisted into mongodb but whatever is in my conversion pattern is not respected.  My desire is to store the line number in the log message.

Here's my log4j property file

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.springframework.data.mongodb.log4j.MongoLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] [%L] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.stdout.host = localhost 
log4j.appender.stdout.port = 27017
log4j.appender.stdout.database = prod
log4j.appender.stdout.collectionPattern = logs
log4j.appender.stdout.applicationId = horizon
log4j.appender.stdout.warnOrHigherWriteConcern = FSYNC_SAFE

log4j.category.org.springframework.batch=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.transaction=INFO
```

Below is what is being stored in Mongo.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f720482788d6140dacb0270"), "applicationId" : "test", "na
me" : "com.service.MongoTest", "level" : "DEBUG", "timestamp
" : ISODate("2012-03-27T18:18:42.981Z"), "properties" : { "applicationId" : "test" }, "message" : "Debug TEST3" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Spring's source code, it doesn't seem to be implemented.  Instead I found another project that has line numbers and custom conversion patterns implemented.  The project is
http://log4mongo.org/